# Serializing an instance of an Interface that have a definition of a list of another interface

Tags: c#, xml-serialization

This might sound like a repeated question from other topics, but it defers in the Interface definition.

I have an Interface, lets say named **IClass1**, which contains in its definition a list of interfaces, say **IClass2**

I have a business unit to implement this interface; implementation naturally will be like this

```
class Class1: IClass1
{
    ....whatever properties
    List<IClass2> DataItems { get; set; }
}

class Class2:IClass2
{
    ...whatever properties
}
```

The problem is that, `XmlSerializer` will complain about the list in Class1, because it is an interface!
So my question is: Simply, I always know what is the type of the instances that should be de-serialized in DataItems list, which will be of type Class2, how to tell my XML serializer that?

I've saw a lot of workarounds, using a dummy properties and ignore the list of interfaces during the serializing/de-serializing process is the most suitable one I think, and I i certainly don't want to invent my own serializer or re implement serialization in my classes

Answer (score 1):

If you are using DataContracts, you can use [`KnownTypeAttribute`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.knowntypeattribute.aspx) to give the deserializer a list of one or more types that it should use when deserializing.

The [version that takes a string parameter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms584302.aspx) lets you specify the name of a method that will return a sequence of types, which can be easier to use in some circumstances.

The link I gave has some sample code at the end of the page.

Comment: @simsim It's ok, it works with .Net 3.0, 3.5 and 4.0 too. Click the "other versions" dropdown on the help page.

Comment: Yea, I was missing to add a reference, System.Runtime.Serialization.
Any way, this will not work also, as I saw in the sample codes, my interface must be aware of the classes that will inherit it :)
In my case, the interfaces are in a separated project; the implementation is separated from the definition

Comment: @simsim "my interface must be aware of the classes that will inherit it" - That sounds very wrong. There's something wrong with your design if that's the case.

Comment: It's a cross application scenario, thats why I need the interface separated from the implementation

Comment: If i want to go extreme with a customized awesome solution, I would use some reflection, unity, and/or mappers
but this will be waste of time, the project is very simple, it only transfers a file across applications. The file will be serialized from the first application, and deserialized in the others